# Floating 3 items side by side

Tags: css, list

I'm trying to get three blocks of items to float side by side but can't get it. [This is the web page test](http://sdms.co.nz/index4.html) I have, with the HTML structured thus:

```
<div id="thumb1">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/JohnShort200x233.jpg" alt="" width="120" border="0" /></li>
        <li>John Short</li>
        <li>Gynaecologist</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="thumb2">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/JohnFrye200x233.jpg" alt="John Frye - General Surgeon" width="120" border="0"></li>
        <li>John Frye</li>
        <li>General Surgeon</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="thumb3">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/RichardGearry200x233.jpg" alt="Richard Gearry - Gastroenterologist" width="120" border="0"></li>
        <li>Richard Gearry</li>
        <li>Gastroenterologist</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...and with the following CSS:

```
ul {width: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 650px;
    float: left;}

ul li {width: 120px;
    list-style: none;}

li {list-style: none;
    text-align: center;}

#thumb1 {float: left;}
```

I need the photo, name and title of each person to stay in one block - with the next block beside it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try  `ul li{float: left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` for `li` and remove `float:left`

```
 li {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        display:inline-block
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`width: 650px;` from `ul`.

```
ul {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to center align the text Horizontally you can use this..

```
li {
width: 120px;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the current code for every div you can set float:left and width 33%

Like

You can add this style

```
div
{
  float: left;
  width: 33%
}
```

Comment: This will  be for testing or learning. Not for production code